# adding any function doesn't allow page to load

Tags: php

this the the code that load good without adding the the function at the top of the page

```
 <?php


    if (!logged_in()) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
    } 


    ?>

    <h3>Upload image</h3>

    <?php

    if (isset($_FILES['image'], $_POST['image_n'], $_POST['image_description'])) {
    $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $bytes = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $image_n = $_POST['image_n'];
    $image_description = $_POST['image_description'];

    $allowed_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'rar', 'pdf');
    //$image_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $image_name)));

    $image_ext = pathinfo($image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $album_id = $_SESSION['varname'];

    $errors = array();

    if (empty($image_name) || empty($album_id) || empty($image_n) ||     empty($image_description)) {

        $errors[] = 'Something is missing';
    } else {

    if (strlen($album_name) > 55 || strlen($album_description) > 255) {
            $errors[] = 'One or more fields contains too many characters';
        }

    if (in_array($image_ext, $allowed_ext) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'File type not allowed';

    }

    //if ($image_size > 2097152) {
    //  $errors[] = 'Maximum file size is 2mb';
    //}

    if (album_check($album_id) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Couldn\'t upload to that album';
    }

    }

    if (!empty($errors)) {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo $error, '<br />';
        }

    } else {
        $byte = formatSizeUnits($bytes);
        upload_image($image_temp, $image_ext, $album_id, $image_n,    $image_description, $byte);
        header('Location: view_album.php?album_id='.$album_id);
        exit();
    }
    }


    ?>

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="choose">
        <p>Choose a file:<br /><input type="file" name="image" /></p>
        </div>
            <div class="des">
            <p>Name*:<br /><input type="text" name="image_n" maxlength="55"/>  </p>
            <p>Description*:<br /><textarea name="image_description" rows="6" cols="35" maxlength="255"></textarea></p>


        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
        </div>
    </form>
<div class="foot">
<?php   

//include 'template/footer.php';    
?>
</div>
```

but when i add a function like this at the top after php and before if !logged.. of the page it doesn't work

```
 function formatSizeUnits($bytes)
    {
        if ($bytes >= 1073741824)
        {
            $bytes = number_format($bytes / 1073741824, 2) . ' GB';
        }
        elseif ($bytes >= 1048576)
        {
            $bytes = number_format($bytes / 1048576, 2) . ' MB';
        }
        elseif ($bytes >= 1024)
        {
            $bytes = number_format($bytes / 1024, 2) . ' KB';
        }
        elseif ($bytes > 1)
        {
            $bytes = $bytes . ' bytes';
        }
        elseif ($bytes == 1)
        {
            $bytes = $bytes . ' byte';
        }
        else
        {
            $bytes = '0 bytes';
        }

        return $bytes;
    }
```

Any idea what is the problem and how to fix it ?

Comment: set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` at the start of your code.

Comment: What does the error log on your server say?

Comment: where is your header? <html><head> etc

Comment: just the page don't load at all

Comment: page already load well without <html> <head> just when i add the function it doesn't load

Comment: have you turned on the warnings? What is it telling you?

Comment: @Dave thanks i found the problem as Chris answered

Comment: If you got this : Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ... it's because you have blank lines before the `header` function...

Comment: @user2687618 great, but nevertheless, enabling warnings should always be the first thing you try. It will make all debugging much faster.

Comment: @Dave i put echo 'hi'; after every line and check if it print or not and define where is the problem

Comment: @user2687618 hey, I agree with Dave, that is the best way to diagnose your problems and prevents you from getting frustrated :)

Comment: @user2687618 that's… not going to find even a quarter of the bugs you could have. Getting into the habit of enabling warnings will save you an awful lot of time. Trust me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it's not working is because you cannot have any output before calling `header()`. The reason you cannot is because PHP will throw an error that the headers were already sent.

```
if (!logged_in()) {
   header('Location: index.php');
   exit();
}
```

You can't have any output before this `header()` statement, so put your new code after it instead to avoid any problems. Also, make sure that you don't have any HTML before the opening php tag, either.

I also recommend removing those blank lines between your opening PHP tag and that first if statement.

Comment: You can't put any *output* before that, but you can put as much code as you like (as long as it doesn't print/echo any output). This gets a bit subtle because anything outside the `<?php` tags (e.g. HTML code) is also output. Maybe that's what you meant.